# How to synchronize two tables of different MySQL databases on the same machine?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 2 different databases, let say db_one and db_two. Each one has a table. `db1_emp_company` and `db2_emp_info` respectively.

Structure is given below:

```
db_one           |    db_two
__________________________________
db1_emp_company  |    db2_emp_info
__________________________________
phone_no         |    contact_no
emp_email        |    email_add
home_address     |    address
```

These two databases are hosted by two different php websites on the same server.

I want to synchronize these both tables of different databases. For example if a user update the `phone_no` of `db1_emp_company` (in db_one) it should update the `contact_no` of the `db2_emp_info` (in db_two). And if a user update the `emp_email` of `db1_emp_company` (in db_one)it should update the `email_add` of `db2_emp_info` (in db_two). and so on.

Is it possible?

Comment: In your code where you update `database1.table`, you could also add another query to update `databas2.table` everytime

Comment: I m updating my 'database1.table' via a form.

Comment: Yes so that form `action`s somewhere and some PHP code updates your database1.table via any query, so just below that line you could update your `database2.table` aswell

Comment: thanks for reply. can you please provide me a sample code please.

Comment: Uh yes, only if you can provide your code which updates your first database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this purpose you can use transactions.

```
$mysql_host                 = DB_HOST;
$mysql_username             = DB_USER;
$mysql_password             = DB_PASSWORD;
$mysql_database1            = DATABASE1;
$mysql_database2            = DATABASE2;

$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) or die( mysql_error());

/*  Begin Transaction   */
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); 


/*  Insert data from db1 to db2 */
$query  =  "    INSERT INTO $mysql_database1.table1";

$a  =   $mysqli->query($query); 

$query  =  "    INSERT INTO $mysql_database1.table2
            SELECT 
                *
            FROM $mysql_database2.table2
            WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * from $mysql_database1.table2)     
";
$d  =   $mysqli->query($query); 


if ($a and $b) 
{
    $mysqli->commit();      
    echo "Data synched successfully.";
} else {        

    $mysqli->rollback();        
    echo "Data failed to synch.";
}
```

If one query fails it will not allow the other to run and will roll back. This is only example code. You can use update instead of insert.

Comment: how to use this where two different host names. Please help

Comment: @Jyoti just define two separate hosts
`$mysql_host1 = DB_HOST1;`
`$mysql_username1 = DB_USER;`
`$mysql_password1 = DB_PASSWORD1;`
`$mysql_database1 = DATABASE1;`

`$mysql_host2 = DB_HOST1;`
`$mysql_username2 = DB_USER;`
`$mysql_password2 = DB_PASSWORD2;`
`$mysql_database2 = DATABASE2;`

Then open a new db connection when you need to insert data into `mysql_host2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

On updating `db_one` table in site1:

```
 update `db_one`.`db1_emp_company` set phone_no = '1234567890' where conditions_here;
 update `db_two`.`db2_emp_info` set contact_no = '1234567890' where conditions_here;
```

Same thing in `db_two`:

```
 update `db_two`.`db2_emp_info` set contact_no = '1234567890' where conditions_here; #Its a same thing as above
 update `db_one`.`db1_emp_company` set phone_no = '1234567890' where conditions_here;
```

If you post your code which is used for updating things. It will be helpful to give exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqldiff for this issue. Check this page: http://www.mysqldiff.org/index.php